# Understanding Promise deprecation warnings in ArcGIS API for JavaScript?

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I am trying to update legacy map code to the latest ArcGIS version of 4.6 and noticed this warning in the console when querying a feature layer.

```
[esri.core.Promise] DEPRECATED: then() -- use .when(callback, errback) instead
```

So I tried to change then to when, but got `when is not a function` errors. I also tried running the sample code from the [site](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/sample-code/sandbox/index.html?sample=featurelayerview-query) and got the same errors.

```
view.whenLayerView(featureLayer).then(function(lyrView) {
          lyrView.watch("updating", function(val) {
            if (!val) { // wait for the layer view to finish updating

              // query all the features available for drawing.
              lyrView.queryFeatures().then(function(results) {

                graphics = results;

                var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();

                results.forEach(function(result, index) {
                  var attributes = result.attributes;
                  var name = attributes.ZIP + " (" +
                    attributes.PO_NAME + ")"

                  // Create a list zip codes in NY
                  var li = document.createElement("li");
                  li.classList.add("panel-result");
                  li.tabIndex = 0;
                  li.setAttribute("data-result-id", index);
                  li.textContent = name;

                  fragment.appendChild(li);
                });
                // Empty the current list
                listNode.innerHTML = "";
                listNode.appendChild(fragment);
              });
            }
          });
        });
```

I also tried setting the `"esri-promise-compatibility"` flag to 1 but that didn't help. Can't see anything in the docs or community forums about this. Anyone come across this before?

Comment: At which point of your code the error `when is not a function` throws?

Comment: If I change `view.whenLayerView(featureLayer).then(` to `view.whenLayerView(featureLayer).when(`. From the docs it appears that `LayerView` supports when but it doesn't seem to work

ref: https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-views-layers-LayerView.html

Answer (score 1):

At the current Api the `whenLayerView()` is a promise but at the moment 
 it doesn't support the `when()` funcion as you can see below the only supported are :

[image: view.whenLayerView]

Also the warning shown in the console is due to this new version API () , May be it'll be removed or fixed in the newer versions ,

As you can see in this **[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ykLtkbLq/3/)** Example (simple `MapViewew` without layers ), whether using promises or just create a simple map ,

the Warning still printed in console .

so using `view.whenLayerView` is not deprected .  and the problem reside in the new version .

Comment: can you please help me out in related question at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69642934/get-click-of-corresponding-map-marker-in-react-js

Answer (score 0):

This can be very confusing. Not all `then()` should be replaced with `when()`, only `then()` which are implemented on classes, like WebMap, WebScene, MapView, SceneView, Basemap, Ground, Layers, and LayerViews.

The methods return ES6 compatible promises that implement the `then()` method. So in your example you don't need to do anything about the `whenLayerView(layer)` method, because that returns an ES6 compatible promise and that works with then.

You can read more about it in this blog post: https://www.esri.com/arcgis-blog/products/js-api-arcgis/mapping/making-better-promises/